# jQuery / Javascript Prompt with Select inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prompt

title seems clear enough, but we never know.

here's my problem, i got a serie of checkbox, each one is associated to a list of choices.

ie:
Checkbox1

=>   Opt1

=>   Opt2

Checkbox2

=>   Opt1

=>   Opt2

etc.., (with about a dozen options per checkbox)

what i need to do is:

when user check a box, a prompt appear with a Select inside and the result is send as the value of the checkbox.

i've tryed some plugins (ie:jQuery Impromptu) but they all auto-close my select tag wich output something like that

```
<select></select><option></option><option></option>
```

anyone got a solution?

Comment: You could use jquery UI Dialog then add your select option inside and get the value selected as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"><select style="display: none;" id="sel1"><option>.........</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2"><select style="display: none;" id="sel2"><option>.........</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3"><select style="display: none;" id="sel3"><option>.........</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('input[type="checkbox"').click(function()
  {
    if($(this).checked)
    {
      $('#sel'+$(this).attr('id').toString().replace('chk', '')).show();
    }
    else
     $('#sel'+$(this).attr('id').toString().replace('chk', '')).hide();
  });
  $('select').change(function(){
     $('#chk' + $(this).attr('id').toString().replace('sel', '')).val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: like the solution, but the reason for the prompt was to make it really clear (some users of this form barely have a computer and still think Windows 95 is up to date)

Comment: gonna accept your answer since you gave me the lead to do it... 

made a pop-up in Jquery and use your hide show to display whatever options i need... it works :P